# Rails: Retrieve data from postgresDB in custom manner

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any efficient way to retrieve data from postgres DB like in the example

Suppose I have a user table with columns book_id, class_id, is_alive, current_status

Expected output format:

```
{ "#{user.book_id.to_s+ '_' + user.class_id.to_s":  user.is_alive || user.current_status == 'online'}
```

Expected output:

```
{ 
  1_2: true, 
  2_3: false 
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve data in the hash format from the query itself?? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
{ "#{user.book_id}_#{user.class_id}":  user.is_alive || user.current_status == 'online'}
```

You can also use [enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for your current_status column that will enable methods like
`user.online?`

Comment: hmm yeah...but i thats not what i am looking for :(  please let me know if the question is not understandable